# manipulate data - make a new column, then if column has a certain value, replace it with 1-another column value in r

Tags: r

I want a way of doing a few commands in one neat way.

I have a dataframe **f**

I want to create a new column based on the column EAF. I want the new column to be EAF/100 and then IF these values are < 0.5, they are fine, if they're > 0.5, then replace them with the value of 1-EAF

So far I have different lines which do this but I think they're must be a better way

```
f

Chr|Pos|A0|A1|rsID|Beta-A1|P|info|eaf 
1|16021|C|T|NA|0.410|0.26|0.842|0.01   
1|17483|C|T|rs845637483|-0.356|0.32|0.856|0.01    
1|19250|T|C|NA|-0.255|0.54|0.812|0.01  
1|39402|T|TCAA|NA|-0.873|0.37|0.821|0.01   
1|39883|G|C|NA|0.195|0.59|0.808|0.01

## Create new column and divide by 100 

f <- transform(f, maf = eaf/100)

## If the new column has a value of > 0.5, change it to the value of 1-eaf

f %>% mutate(maf = replace(maf, maf >=0.5, 1-eaf))
```

But this last command gives the error

```
Problem while computing `maf = replace(maf, maf >= 0.5, 1 - eaf)`.
i number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Is there a way to fix the latter command, but also do both steps in one call?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code seems to have a  typo.  It should be `f %>% mutate(maf= .` and not `f$maf %>%..`

Comment: With `replace`, you need `values` to be of same length as `list` (second argument) `f %>% mutate(map = replace(maf, maf >= 0.5, 1-eaf[maf >= 0.5]))`